# Nested Layouts MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC so pardon if my questions come across as stupid.

I have a main layout file (_MainLayout.cshtml) and a secondary layout file (_AdminLayout.cshtml). Both these files reside in my /Views/Shared folder.

The _MainLayout.cshtml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/icons/favicon.ico" />
    <title>U - @ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="MainMenu" style="top:45px; height:40px; width:100%; position:fixed">
            <ul style="list-style-type:none; text-align:center">
                <li class="u-li-rightfloatinglink">@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "_AdminLayout", "Admin")</li>
                <li class="u-li-rightfloatinglink">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li class="u-li-rightfloatinglink">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li class="u-li-rightfloatinglink">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="MainBody" style="top: 80px; width:100%; text-align:center; position:fixed">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="MainFooter" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; width:100%; height:20px; background:#015da0">
        <p style="display:table-cell; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; vertical-align: middle">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - U</p>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

The _AdminLayout.cshtml looks like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_AdminLayout";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>_AdminLayout</h2>
<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

The ManageTableContent.cshtml is again supposed to be displayed in the @RenderBody section of the _AdminLayout.cshtml.

ManageTableContent.cshtml looks like:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Table Content";
}
<body>
    <div class="u-div-header">
        <p class="u-p-header">Manage Table Content</p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <table class="u-table-layouttable">
            <tr>
                <td class="u-td-description">Table Name here</td>
                <td class="u-td-buttons">
                    <button class="u-button-addrecord" title="Add Record">
                        <img />
                    </button>
                    <button class="u-button-deleterecord" title="Delete Record">
                        <img />
                    </button>
                    <button class="u-button-clonerecord" title="Clone Record">
                        <img />
                    </button>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table id="ManagedTable" class="u-table-datatable">
                        <tr class="u-tr-datatable">
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="float: right" />
                    <input id="Cancel" type="reset" value="Cancel" style="float: right" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

For some reason if I get this error when I try and open my _AdminLayout.cshtml by selecting the Admin link from my _MainLayout.cshtml:

```
Additional information: The file "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderBody" method.
```

Controller Code:

```
namespace U.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Admin
        public ActionResult ManageTableContent()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult _AdminLayout()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your admin page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `@RenderBody()`from my code then the _AdminLayout.cshtml loads fine.
I need the `@RenderBody()` in my _AdminLayout.cshtml because here I will display partial Views again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I get this error when I try and open my _AdminLayout.cshtml from my _MainLayout.cshtml- please clarify more clearly

Comment: On my _MainLayout.cshtml I have a few links. One of the links will in turn call/open/display the _AdminLayout.cshtml in the @RenderBody() section of the _MainLayout.cshtml.

Comment: I actually dont understand. I dont know what is problem of sharing code with us. From your saying you call _MainLayout from _Adminlayout and _AdminLayout from _MainLayout. This is kind of recursive. If you kindly share your code then possibly people can help you.

Comment: can I see you controller code. Basically I also do that way but I dont get any error like that.

Comment: Controller code added

Comment: when do you find error ?
when you call _AdminLayout action ? or when you call ManageTableContent action? or both time ?

Comment: When you call _AdminLayout action

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one @RenderBody() per master layout (that's where the output of a View goes to).

If _AdminLayout.cshtml is not a master layout, then you should use @RenderPartial to insert partial views there.

Comment: How do I know if my layout is a master layout?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, 
when you call _AdminLayout action 
then it calls automatically _AdminLayout.cshtml and as it has  @RenderBody() method in his view file it get error. Action controller view can not hold  @RenderBody().

you can do that way. Change your  ActionResult _AdminLayout name to AdminLayout.

And create another view file named AdminLayout.cshtml.

And in that cshtml you can code this way.

```
 @{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
  ViewBag.Title = "Manage Table Content";
 }
```

I hope you understand why do you get this error.

Comment: Anik, I am sorry, I just can't wrap my head around this.